# Can I visit my father in the USA?

Tags: usa, uk, uk-citizens

My father is a resident in the USA, California.

I'm a Polish national, resident in the UK. I've had one jab of the Pfizer vaccine (so partially vaccinated).

Can I fly to the USA for a few weeks and come back to the UK? Would I have to quarantine in the USA or the UK?

I looked here (https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/usa/entry-requirements) but it wasn't too clear!

Comment: Are you under 21 years of age, and if so, are you married?

Comment: @Doc I'm 22, not married

Comment: You may probably want fly for a few weeks say to Mexico and then the US.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule, you will NOT be allowed enter the US coming from the UK (or most of Europe).

The full details of the rules [are available here](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/covid-19-travel-restrictions-and-exceptions.html), but realistically the only way that you would be allowed enter on the grounds that your father is a resident of the US (presuming he is a "permanent resident". ie, a green card holder) is if you were under 21 years of age and unmarried.

The only other option would be for you to have not been physically present in the UK (or the Schengen region or several other countries, [listed here](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/from-other-countries.html)) within the 14 days prior to entering the US.

Vaccination status currently does not have any impact on these rules, and even if it did, being anything other that fully vaccinated (in your case, 2 weeks after your 2nd shot) would almost certainly count for nothing anyway.

Comment: Do we know when these rules will change please?

Comment: At this stage, nobody knows.

Comment: @Mike No one can predict the future, even the governments that make the rules cannot predict. So the answer is no, no one knows when the rules might change. Given the Delta variant's spread, the rules may well become more restrictive before they ease.

Comment: The latest reports indicate that there will be no change in the near future. [2021-07-26: BBC News - White House: US to maintain Covid foreign travel restrictions](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-57976015)

Comment: @Mike I wouldn’t count on them changing in the next 6 months. If you have to go, go now via a third country, don’t hope for any changes.

Comment: Just to be clear, “via a third country” means you need to stay at least 14 days in a country not listed in the US travel bans before travelling to the US. Don’t even think about trying to shorten that time and hiding it from the US authorities.