# Can I leave USA as a US citizen prior to end of 2-week quarantine after arrival

Tags: usa, uk, us-citizens, covid-19, quarantine

Somewhat related to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168365/can-i-visit-my-father-in-the-usa-if-im-fully-vaccinated), but not duplicate.

I am a dual USA/UK citizen residing in the UK.  General travel from the UK to USA is currently banned; however, the USA does allow its citizens to enter the country. I'd like to visit my mother in the USA (in Massachusetts) in November.  (Hopefully, the rules will change by then, so my question relates to the case if they do not.)

The way I read the rules/regulations, as a US citizen, I will be allowed to enter the USA, however I will need to self-quarantine for 14 days at my place of stay.  This generally wouldn't be much of an issue - I'm specifically going to visit my mother and if I have to spend my time in her home with her, that's not an issue.  However I cannot stay in the USA for 2 weeks - I have to return to the UK prior to that.

So, the question becomes: am I allowed to leave the USA prior to the expiration of this 2-week quarantine? How would that work in the airport?

Comment: [Am I allowed to go to the airport to catch a flight if I am supposed to self-quarantine in California, United States?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158793/am-i-allowed-to-go-to-the-airport-to-catch-a-flight-if-i-am-supposed-to-self-qua)

Comment: The US has no exit controls. Nobody will stop you from leaving, and I'm *very* skeptical that state health authorities will care if you leave early (provided you have quarantined for the entire duration of your visit).

Answer (score 6):

There is no federal requirement for quarantine after arriving in the US. Quarantine requirements are at the state level.

According to [mass.gov](https://www.mass.gov/info-details/covid-19-isolation-and-quarantine-information):

> Quarantine is also recommended for unvaccinated individuals who have traveled outside of Massachusetts.
>
> (...)
>
> individuals who have received either two doses of the Moderna or Pfizer COVID-19 vaccines or a single dose of the Janssen COVID-19 vaccine, at least 14 days ago are not required to quarantine following an exposure.

So my understanding is that, in Massachusetts:

- if you are fully vaccinated you don't need to quarantine
- if you aren't, it's a recommendation, not a requirement.

So there's no problem for you to leave before the 14 days.

Remember however that before travel to the US, you **need to get a negative test less than 3 days before departure**. [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/international-travel-during-covid19.html) also **recommends** that you get tested 3 to 5 days after your arrival in the US in all cases, and self-quarantine for 7 days if you are unvaccinated (or 10 days if you don't get tested).

If you are unvaccinated, they also recommend avoiding being around people who are at increased risk for severe illness for 14 days, whether you get tested or not.

So, get vaccinated if you aren't already (if you start now you should be over the 14 days after the second injection by November), get tested less than 3 days before travel, and enjoy your trip.

Comment: Thanks.  I am vaccinated, but with the Oxford AstraZeneca , not one of the above.

Comment: @AleksG The vaccines listed are for avoiding quarantine after exposure. In your case, quarantine is only a recommendation anyway.